# Error "linkage specification is not allowed" when using extern "C" with __declspec(dllexport) in a C++ class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, shared-libraries, dllexport

When I am using using extern "C" with __declspec(dllexport) in the Class, then I am getting an error **"linkage specification is not allowed".**

If i declare this outside of the class then i am not getting any error.

Could someone please help me how to use extern "C" with __declspec(dllexport) with in the Class

Below is the code snippet:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define DECLSPEC extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MyClass
{
DECLSPEC static std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> GetInstance();
};
```

Comment: Obviously, you cannot combine any C++ features with `extern "C"`, which means "expose in a way that C code can call it". Why do you feel you need `extern "C"`?

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, GetProcAddress is retuning nullptr and i am seeing error code "127". I am suspecting that if i use extern "C" this error will resolve.

Comment: You'll have to use a mangled name for `GetProcAddress` to work with a C++ function. Further, it's unwise to use C++ classes like `shared_ptr` in a DLL interface - it would only work if both the DLL and the calling module are built with the same version of the same compiler using the same settings (in particular, the same C++ runtime DLL). Because otherwise, they may not agree on the definition of `shared_ptr`, and/or one module won't be able to deallocate memory allocated by the other. And once you build everything together, it's mostly pointless to use `GetProcAddress`

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik for the information. As you suggested, we are using the DLL and the calling module with the same settings. I am trying to test the DLL using the unit test where i am getting error code "127" when using GetProcAddress. For that reason i am trying to use extern "C". Is it possible to use extern "C" with a C++ function?

Comment: No, it is not. Link with the import library for the DLL (this way you don't need to use `GetProcAddress`), or pass a mangled name to `GetProcAddress`. You could use e.g. [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to discover the mangled name under which the function got exported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415694/loading-dll-at-runtime