# Loading dll at runtime

Tags: c++, interface, c++17, dllexport, pure-virtual

I need to load a DLL at runtime. I don't know in advance which DLL to load, but DLLs are the implementation of an interface (pure virtual method). The final goal is to have a pointer to a DLL to call its methods.

Now, I want to test just the DLL loading, calling a test method, but I fail. The test method is `void test()`.

```cpp
#if defined (_WIN32)
const path PluginExtension(".dll");
#define STDCALL __stdcall
#else
const path PluginExtension(".so");
#define STDCALL
#endif

extern "C"
{    
    typedef void*  (STDCALL* CreatorFunction)();
        
    constexpr auto FunctionName{ "CommandGeneratorEngine::Interface::test" };
}

auto library = LoadLibraryExW(pluginPath.native().c_str(), nullptr, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
if (library != nullptr) {
                
    auto creator = (CreatorFunction)GetProcAddress(library, FunctionName);
    if (creator != nullptr) {
        // do something 
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::exception("Error when loading comm plugin");
    }
```

The interface

```cpp
namespace TGComm {
namespace CommandGeneratorEngine {
    
class Interface {
public:
        
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Interface>;
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    
    virtual  void test() = 0;
         
};

}
}
```

And the interface implementation:

```cpp
class LHFImplementationInterface : public CommandGeneratorEngine::Interface
{
public:

    void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall test() override{
        // do something...
    }
};
```

The line

```cpp
auto creator = (CreatorFunction)GetProcAddress(library, FunctionName);
```

returns a null value.

Comment: If you look at your DLL exports you will notice the C++ names are mangled. You need to research how to GetProcAddress of a mangled name.

Comment: Even if you could import the mangled name, it wouldn't help.  You won't be able to call `test()` without an `Interface`-derived object to call it on.  The DLL needs to export a flat C-style function to obtain an `Interface*` pointer to such an object, and then the caller can call methods on that object.

Comment: Why not using the "normal" approach: the *.dll* exports a factory function (smth like `CommandGeneratorEngine::Interface* createEngine()` that returns a pointer to the *LHFImplementationInterface*) and then load and call that function from the client *app*, (without the *extern "C"*)?

Comment: `CommandGeneratorEngine::Interface::test` doesn't match the signature of `CreatorFunction` anyway. Somewhere in that DLL there should be an exported function that takes no parameters and returns `void*` - that's the one you want to access with `GetProcAddress`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I created a new header file, h1.h

```
#include "Global.h"

extern "C" {

LHCOMMQT_LIB void* createTGCommPlugin();

}
```

its cpp is

```
#include "h1.h"
#include "LHFImplementationinterface.h"

void* createTGCommPlugin() {
    auto p = new LHFImplementationInterface();
    return p;
}
```

and global.h is

```
#ifndef LHCOMM_GLOBAL_H
#define LHCOMM_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#ifdef LHCOMMQT_EXPORTS
# define LHCOMMQT_LIB Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else // ifdef LHCOMMQT_EXPORTS
# define LHCOMMQT_LIB Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif // ifdef LHCOMMQT_EXPORTS

#endif // LHCOMM_GLOBAL_H
```

in main:

```
typedef void* (STDCALL* CreatorFunction)();
constexpr auto FunctionName{ "createTGCommPlugin" };
try {
    auto library = LoadLibraryExW(pluginPath.native().c_str(), nullptr, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
    if (library != nullptr) {
    
        auto creator = (CreatorFunction)GetProcAddress(library, FunctionName);
...
```

and now works good